# Denormalize array of columns into multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Why column 'x' is always 't2'? I need it to be 't2', 't3', 't4'.... and the result should be 9 rows, not 3.

```
import pandas as pd
rows  = [{'id': 'x1', 'seq': 0, 'amount': 2000, 'payments': 4, 'dummy': 1 },
          {'id': 'x2', 'seq': 0, 'amount': 4000, 'payments': 2, 'dummy': 11 },
          {'id': 'x3', 'seq': 0, 'amount': 9000, 'payments': 3, 'dummy': 111 }]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

def generate_array(row):
    times2 = row['amount'] + row['payments'] * 2
    times3 = row['amount'] + row['payments'] * 3
    times4 = row['amount'] + row['payments'] * 4
    
    result = [ { 'x': 't2', 'y': times2 }, 
               { 'x': 't3', 'y': times3 }, 
               { 'x': 't4', 'y': times4 } ]
    return result

df['complete_schedule'] = df.apply(generate_array, axis=1)

df_normalized = df['complete_schedule'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]) )

print(df_normalized)


    x   y
0   t2  2008
1   t2  4004
2   t2  9006
```

Instead, I need the result to be:

```
    x   y
0   t2  2008
1   t2  2012
2   t2  2016
3   t3  4008
4   t3  4012
5   t3  4016
6   t4  9008
7   t4  9012
8   t4  9016
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense. Can you *double-check* ? The order of the `x` values is messed up (e.g 2nd row should be `t3|2012`) and also some of the `y` values are wrong (e.g last row should be `t4|9012`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generate_array` function has to generate a list of dictionaries based on the `x` value:

```
def generate_array(row):
    result = []
    for i in range(2, row['payments'] + 2):
        times = row['amount'] + row['payments'] * i
        result.append({'x': f't{i}', 'y': times})
    return result
```